# OpenXmlDoc Word: How to add Mark an item for indexing?

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using DocumentFormat.OpenXml to generate a Word document programmatically.

In the [conceptual content for Word](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-content/blob/master/en-us/OpenXMLCon/articles/4fcb7fbb-0796-4737-8f05-acbcfa9e1a06.md), I can't find any mention for marking items so that they can be included in the document index. What classes can I use for this?

I did a very simple document containing just `This is an apple.` with an `an apple` marked for indexing with Main entry: apple. The Xml content is as follows:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="000975CB" w:rsidRDefault="00B83C06" w:rsidP="007969F3">
 <w:r>
  <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is </w:t>
 </w:r>
 <w:r w:rsidR="007969F3"><w:t>an apple</w:t></w:r>
 <w:r><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/></w:r>
 <w:r><w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> XE "</w:instrText></w:r>
 <w:r w:rsidRPr="00246108"><w:instrText>apple</w:instrText></w:r>
 <w:r><w:instrText xml:space="preserve">" </w:instrText></w:r>
 <w:r><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/></w:r>
 <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
 <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
 <w:r><w:t>.</w:t></w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="007969F3" w:rsidRPr="007969F3" w:rsidRDefault="007969F3" w:rsidP="007969F3"/>
...
```

Comment: The best way, really, to research something like this is to : 1) Create a *very* small sample document with the content you want to work with; 2) Open the document in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. 3) View the XML; 4) Look carefully at the code the Tool generates to recreate the document. That should give you the starting point (the objects) to continue research in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had earlier created a simple test document but inspected using notepad instead. Didn't know about the Productivity Tool and the reflection feature. The reflected code helped me to reproduce the mark-up needed to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An item marked for indexing is a [field code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.fieldcode(v=office.14).aspx) (`w:instrText`) of type **[XE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/field-codes-xe-index-entry-field-abaf7c78-6e21-418d-bf8b-f8186d2e4d08?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)**. A field code has to be inside a [complex field character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.fieldchar(v=office.14).aspx) (`w:fldChar`).

The pertinent markup in the sample document is:

```
<w:r><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/></w:r>
  <w:r><w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> XE "</w:instrText></w:r>
  <w:r><w:instrText>apple</w:instrText></w:r>
  <w:r><w:instrText xml:space="preserve">" </w:instrText></w:r>
<w:r><w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/></w:r>
```

The field code elements shown above can be combined together as:

```
<w:r><w:instrText>XE "apple"</w:instrText></w:r>
```

Sample code to produce above:

```
Tuple<Run,Run,Run> MarkEntryForIndex(string item)
{
    Run run0 = new Run();
     FieldChar fieldChar1 = new FieldChar() { FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.Begin };
     run0.Append(fieldChar1);
    Run run1 = new Run();
     FieldCode fieldCode1 = new FieldCode() { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve };
     fieldCode1.Text = " XE \"" + item + "\"";
     run1.Append(fieldCode1);
    Run run2 = new Run();
     FieldChar fieldChar2 = new FieldChar() { FieldCharType = FieldCharValues.End };
     run2.Append(fieldChar2);
    return Tuple.Create(run0, run1, run2);
}
```